# How to use Pyfolio or some related tool that that generates reports of time series data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across this link today.

https://www.activestate.com/blog/top-10-python-packages-for-finance-and-financial-modeling/

I came across #7 Pyfolio, and I tried to test it on my time series data, which looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'load_date': '2017-06-30', 'revenue':'1050'}, 
       {'load_date': '2017-07-31', 'revenue':'44500'},
       {'load_date': '2017-08-31', 'revenue':'38100'}, 
       {'load_date': '2017-09-30',  'revenue':'10000'},
       {'load_date': '2017-10-31',  'revenue':'90000'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

So, when In run the sample code from the site, like this...

```
import pyfolio as pf

mth_returns = df.set_index('load_date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).mean()
mth_returns.head()

pf.create_returns_tear_sheet(mth_returns, live_start_date='2017-12-1')
```

I get this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-223-e605f44299ce> in <module>
      7 mth_returns.head()
      8 
----> 9 pf.create_returns_tear_sheet(mth_returns, live_start_date='2017-12-1')

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyfolio/plotting.py in call_w_context(*args, **kwargs)
     50         if set_context:
     51             with plotting_context(), axes_style():
---> 52                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     53         else:
     54             return func(*args, **kwargs)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyfolio/tears.py in create_returns_tear_sheet(returns, positions, transactions, live_start_date, cone_std, benchmark_rets, bootstrap, turnover_denom, header_rows, return_fig)
    494         returns = utils.clip_returns_to_benchmark(returns, benchmark_rets)
    495 
--> 496     plotting.show_perf_stats(returns, benchmark_rets,
    497                              positions=positions,
    498                              transactions=transactions,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyfolio/plotting.py in show_perf_stats(returns, factor_returns, positions, transactions, turnover_denom, live_start_date, bootstrap, header_rows)
    584         perf_func = timeseries.perf_stats
    585 
--> 586     perf_stats_all = perf_func(
    587         returns,
    588         factor_returns=factor_returns,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyfolio/timeseries.py in perf_stats(returns, factor_returns, positions, transactions, turnover_denom)
    724     stats = pd.Series()
    725     for stat_func in SIMPLE_STAT_FUNCS:
--> 726         stats[STAT_FUNC_NAMES[stat_func.__name__]] = stat_func(returns)
    727 
    728     if positions is not None:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/empyrical/stats.py in calmar_ratio(returns, period, annualization)
    582 
    583     max_dd = max_drawdown(returns=returns)
--> 584     if max_dd < 0:
    585         temp = annual_return(
    586             returns=returns,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1535     @final
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
   1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I Googled that, of course. I didn't find anything super-useful. Anyone know how this pyfolio thing works? I was just looking at the charts and graphs for pyfolio, and it looks quite impressive. Thanks.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Just made that update.

Comment: I tried to run code but first I get error because `load_data` is not converted to Datetime`, next it needs to convert `revenue` to `int`. Finally I got your error but still don't know what makes problem.

Comment: I didn't post code to convert those datatypes; mine was already datatime and int. Yeah, I don't know what the problem is. I scanned through the documentation and I still can't figure it out.